# Returning a generic type through an associated type

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types

I try to get something more generic done but am failing on trying it with associated types. Given is a `Shape` trait and a `Renderer` type which tries to return a `Builder` for a specific kind of shape.

**shape**

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Rectangle{
    pub origin: Point,
    pub height: usize,
    pub width: usize,
}

pub trait Shape{
    type Builder : ShapeBuilder;
}

impl Shape for Rectangle{
    type Builder = RectangleBuilder;
}
```

**builder**

```
pub trait ShapeBuilder{
    type Renderer: ShapeRenderer;
    fn set_origin() -> Self::Renderer;
}

pub struct RectangleBuilder;

impl ShapeBuilder for RectangleBuilder{
    type Renderer = RectangleRenderer;
    fn set_origin() -> Self::Renderer{
        RectangleRenderer
    }
}
```

**renderer**

```
pub struct Renderer<'a>{
    canvas:&'a mut Canvas
}

impl <'a>Renderer<'a>{
    pub fn new(canvas:&'a mut Canvas) -> Renderer {
        Renderer{
            canvas: canvas
        }
    }
    pub fn set_shape<T: Shape>(&self, shape: T) -> T::Builder{
        // trying to return the specific builder through shape::Builder
        // or something like that
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the `set_shape` method will return the `RectangleBuilder` **if** the given `shape` is of type `Rectangle`

Comment: Do the builders need parameters in order to initialize a new instance, or are they supposed to be constructible without parameters?

Comment: actually yes - bit is some kind of stub implementation - first want to achieve the transition from the renderer to the returning builder. You may already realized that I try to create a builder pattern here.

Comment: I think I didn't phrase my first comment correctly. In order to construct a builder, do you need parameters, or must each implementation of `ShapeBuilder` support construction without parameters?

Comment: construction will be without parameters. The Call of  `set_origin()` will be the only way to set a state for the builder - the origin of the shape to be rendered actually

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a static method in the `ShapeBuilder` trait that instantiates a new `Self`. A static method is just a method with no `self` parameter.

You can either add a method directly:

```
pub trait ShapeBuilder: Sized {
    type Renderer: ShapeRenderer;

    fn new() -> Self;
    fn set_origin() -> Self::Renderer;
}
```

or be clever and define `ShareBuilder` as a subtrait of [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html).

```
pub trait ShapeBuilder: Default {
    type Renderer: ShapeRenderer;

    fn set_origin() -> Self::Renderer;
}
```

Then, in `set_shape`, you can instantiate the `ShapeBuilder`:

```
impl <'a>Renderer<'a>{
    pub fn set_shape<T: Shape>(&self, shape: T) -> T::Builder {
        ShapeBuilder::new() // or Default::default()
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example. When setting a `Rectangle` object as `shape` argument - will `ShapeBuilder::new()` return a RectangleBuilder? Because I do not understand how it resolves if the returning Builder would be a `RectangleBuilder` since you simply return `Self` and not something like `Self::ShapeBuilder` (which is wrong syntax I know)

Comment: @xetra11 Yes. `Self` in trait definition means "the concrete type that implements this trait". In this case, `RectangleBuilder`. You can also write `T::Builder::new()` or `<T::Builder as ShapeBuilder>::new()` instead of just `ShapeBuilder::new()`, if that's clearer for you.

Comment: Ah okay...so implicitly it knows that I'm talking about the associated Type of `T` if I call `ShapeBuilder::new()` - pretty much magic and very bad readability don't you think so, too?

Comment: It's not magic if you know the rules. :) But seriously, this is just one instance of the compiler inferring the type of an expression from the return type specified in the function's signature. Another example: If you return the result of [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect), then the compiler will infer which type of collection you want from the function's return type.